# TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile выдаёт ошибку -1

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

Пытаюсь реализовать сохранения результата **TextToSpeech.speak()** в файл. В **TextToSpeech** предусмотрен метод **synthesizeToFile**, но при его вызове он возвращает ошибку с кодом -1.

Вот код который я использую

```
    public void saveInFile(View view) {
        String speakTextTxt = "Good morning,have a nice day";
        HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, speakTextTxt);

        String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File appTmpPath = new File(exStoragePath);
        appTmpPath.mkdirs();
        String tempFilename = "aud12445.wav";
        String tempDestFile = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + tempFilename;

        int i = ttp.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, tempDestFile);
        if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Файл сохраняется в корень устройства. В **AndroidManifest** стоит разрешение     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Одного разрешения мало в манифесте. Надо ещё запрос вставить

Comment: вставлял - бестолку

Comment: Что вставляли, покажите

Comment: ```        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            crntActivity.requestPermissions(permissions, 123);
        }```

Comment: сохраняйте в getExternalFilesDir

Comment: пробовал, не пмогает\